# Mysterious behaviour of seq and == operator. A precision issue?

Tags: r, precision, seq

I've come across a somehow weird (or just not expected?) behaviour of the function `seq`.
When creating a simple sequence some values cannot be matched correctly with the == operator.
See this minimal example:

```
my.seq <- seq(0, 0.4, len = 5)
table(my.seq)                  # ok! returns  0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
                               #              1   1   1   1   1 

which(my.seq == 0.2)           # ok! returns  3
which(my.seq == 0.3)           # !!! returns  integer(0)
```

When creating my sequence manually, it seems to work, though:

```
my.seq2 <- c(0.00, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40)

which(my.seq2 == 0.3)           # ok! returns  4
```

Do you have any explanation for that? I solved the issue by using `which(round(my.seq, 2) == 0.3)` but I would be interested in what's causing the problem.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: See the documentation for `?'=='`, particularly the section entitled "Note".

Comment: Thank you. I just was not aware of that there could be any problem in this simple case, but `seq` does some calculations, so there is. Well, I will definitely be more careful the next time an just use `round`? (I mean to apply `isTRUE(all.equal(x, 0.3))` to the sequence would be a bit of overkill, wouldn't it? :))

Comment: Whether it's overkill or not depends on how many bugs you're ok with in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers just don't represent floating point numbers well.  The general tendencies of spreadsheets to hide this has, as the primary way most people deal with numbers on computers, lead to many problems.

Never match against exact floating point values.  There are functions in R to deal with this (e.g. `all.equal`) but I prefer the following.

Say you have an unknown floating point variable A and you want to see if it is equal to 0.5.

```
abs(A - 0.5) < tol
```

Set tolerance to how close you need it to 0.5.  For example, `tol  <-  0.0001` might be fine for you.

If your values look like they should be integers just round.  Or, if you know the decimal level that you want to test to then you can round to that decimal level.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I am aware of the problem, I think, I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: The default tolerance `all.equal` uses is `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`, or `1.490116e-08`. So, to replicate the results of `all.equal`, you can use @John's method with that as the tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

Computers have a tough time storing exact values.

```
> options(digits=22)
> seq(0, .4, len = 5)
[1] 0.0000000000000000000000 0.1000000000000000055511 0.2000000000000000111022
[4] 0.3000000000000000444089 0.4000000000000000222045
> .4
[1] 0.4000000000000000222045
> c(0, .1, .2, .3, .4)
[1] 0.0000000000000000000000 0.1000000000000000055511 0.2000000000000000111022
[4] 0.2999999999999999888978 0.4000000000000000222045
```

Since we're using a binary floating point representation we can't represent the values of interest exactly.  It looks since the value for .4 is a little bit higher than .4 that the value for .3 is a little bit higher than if you would type .3 itself.  I'm sure somebody else will provide a better explanation for this but hopefully this sheds some light on the issue.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. I suspected something like that to be the problem. What do you suggest then? Never match against exact values, always round before comparison?

Comment: Don't do the rounding yourself.  Check out what joran's comment is pointing you to.  I'm sure that will lead you to `all.equal` at some point.

Comment: It dit. But in this simple case, I think, I will stick with round or do it with some tolerance as John (above) suggests.

Answer (score 2):

This is [FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), which also has a link to a longer discussion of the problem in general.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)