# Approximate match (analogue of all.equal for identical)?

Tags: r, precision

Consider:

```
(tmp1 <- seq(0, 0.2, 0.01)[16])
# [1] 0.15
(tmp2 <- seq(0, 0.2, 0.05)[4])
# [1] 0.15
```

and

```
identical(tmp1, tmp2)
# [1] FALSE
all.equal(tmp1, tmp2) # test for 'near' equality
[1] TRUE
```

The underlying reason is to do with [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742556/mysterious-behaviour-of-seq-and-operator-a-precision-issue). However, this leads to a problem when trying to identify subsequences within sequences using `match`, for example:

```
match(seq(0, 0.2, 0.05), seq(0, 0.2, 0.01))
# [1]  1  6 11 NA 21
```

Is there an alternative to `match` that is the analogue of `all.equal` for `identical`?

Comment: Maybe with `round` ? `match(round(tmp2, 2), round(tmp1, 2))`

Comment: That's a good idea, so I just need to choose the digits argument cleverly.

Comment: @Alex - `round` most definitely works on vectors. It would be rather useless otherwise.

Comment: @thelatemail oops, misread the bit in the helpfile about round :)

Answer (score 1):

We can write a custom `match` called `near.match`, inspired by `dplyr::near`:

```
near.match <- function(x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5){
    sapply(x, function(i){
       res <- which(abs(y - i) < tol, arr.ind = TRUE)[1]
       if(length(res)) res else NA_integer_
    })
}

near.match(seq(0, 0.2, 0.05), seq(0, 0.2, 0.01))
# [1]  1  6 11 16 21
near.match(c(seq(0, 0.2, 0.05), 0.3), seq(0, 0.2, 0.01))
# [1]  1  6 11 16 21 NA
```

Comment: while I like the logic of this answer (using `double.eps`), I think more efficiency can be obtained  by building in your logic to the `round` function

Comment: @Alex, i think giving a `tol` is more flexible, while the drawback is less effeciency.